# Replace s substring from array of string - Python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

How to remove a substring from the following string  'AA.01.001 Hello' with regular expression using Python.

I tried the following but, not worked.

```
array= ['AB.01.001 Hello','BA.10.004','CD.10.015 Good bye']
 regex = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{2,3}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{3}')
filtered = filter(lambda i: not regex.search(i), array)

Edit:

Exprected output : [`Hello`,'Good bye']
```

Comment: I think the pattern works right? Just add `\s*` after it to account for the whitespaces and use a single backslash. https://regex101.com/r/Jkht46/1 See Python demo https://ideone.com/rZfGLP

Comment: can you add some more examples to it, will the string to replace is always in this format `'AA.01.001 `

Comment: I think the issue is just the double backslashes. You are using a raw string. So you only need one backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `re.sub`:

```
import re
array= ['AB.01.001 Hello','BA.10.004','CD.10.015 Good bye']
regex = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\s*')
filtered = filter(None, map(lambda i: regex.sub('', i), array))
print(list(filtered))
# => ['Hello', 'Good bye']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bQ0Ahk).

Note I used only one `\` to escape the literal dots (as you are using a raw string literal to define the regex) and added `\s*` to also remove any 0 or more whitespaces after your pattern.

**Details**

- `map(lambda i: regex.sub('', i), array)` - iterates over the `array` items and removes the matches with `re.sub`
- `filter(None, ...)` removes the empty items resulting from the substitution when the pattern matches the whole string.